# Regular expression for a search string needed

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a RegEx for an alphanumeric string in .NET with optional asterisks only at the beginning or / and at the end of the string. Not in the middle of the string.

Examples:

```
Ab123Zr5M => Match
*Ab123Zr5M => Match 
Ab123Zr5M* => Match
*Ab12*3Zr5M => No Match
Ab12*3Zr5M => No Match
Ab12*3Zr5M* => No Match
```

Here's what I have but id doesn't seem to work.

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\*]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[0-9a-zA-Z\\*]$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the asterix in the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9\\*]+` (note that you don't have to escape it, now it will match a backslash as well) allows it to match any of the listed 1+ times.

You could match either at the left or at the right side:

```
^(?:\*[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\*?)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GFb9yZ/1)

If they also can be at both sides:

```
^\*?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\*?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6zUeyC/1)

Comment: That seems to work so far, great! How could I add the match case of having one (!) asterisk only?
* => Match

Comment: @C4RL0 There are multliple ways to do that

https://regex101.com/r/SjPMj3/1 `^(?:\*[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\*?|\*)$`

or 

`^(?:\*?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\*?|\*)$` https://regex101.com/r/4tfy2o/1

Comment: thanks a lot, the last example was exactly what I needed